# What ActionResult should you return to update just the ActionLink text?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC4 with Entity Framework and like many people I'm new to MVC and trying to get my head around the design patterns.

I have a partial view that displays a list of sessions followed by actionlinks allowing the authenticated member to book into the sessions.

Note: for clarity, I've chopped out most of the code, if a member is booked into a session, it displays "Booked" instead of the action link.

```
@using OnlineBookings.Website.Models
@{ DateTime currentDate = DateTime.MinValue.Date; }

<form method="post" action="~/Controllers/BookSessionController.cs">
@foreach (SessionsWithBookingInformation s in Model)
{
  <p>@s.StartTime.ToString("t") 
            @s.Description 
            @Html.ActionLink(
                            "Book", 
                            "BookSession", 
                            new { sessionId = s.SessionId } 
                            ) 
   </p>
}    
</form>
```

This then displays as part of a larger view:

[image]

The actionlinks pass the guid of the session to be booked through to the following function in my controller, which retrieves the memberId from the cookie and uses Entity Framework to create a booking for that member and session.

```
public ActionResult BookSession(Guid sessionId)
{
    using (var db = new OnlineBookingsEntities())
    {
        // see if the member id is stored in a cookie
        if (Request.Cookies["memberId"] != null)
        {
            var memberId = new Guid(Request.Cookies["memberId"].Value);
            db.Bookings.Add(new Booking
            {
                BookingId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                MemberId = memberId,
                SessionId = sessionId,
                BookingTime = DateTime.Now
            });
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    // this refreshes the entire page
    /// is there a better way to just replace the actionlink they clicked on?
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");   
}
```

All this is working nicely and bookings are being effectively recorded.

But, I'm trying to figure is if the return from the `BookSession` function can just update the actionlink text.

Ideally, on success, I want to replace the ActionLink in my partial view with the word "Booked" and on failure I want to replace it with the failure condition like "Session full".

Or I could just update my partial view, because that will do the same thing.

Am I missing something simple here? Or, am I barking up entirely the wrong tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is great and really well explained, but it's also a little vague since it's a bit of a "What should I do?" question. Here are a few options that might help you develop a solution.

1. **Redisplay the same view.** Return whichever view the user was on for them to submit the link. This will look like a simple refresh.

   ```
   return View();
   ```
2. **Submit the request via AJAX and update via a partial view.** Put an `id` tag on a `span` or similar HTML element with an individual booking's details inside. Submit the request with AJAX, perhaps via `@Ajax.ActionLink`, and have your action return a partial view.

   ```
   return PartialView("_OnlineBookingPartial", model);
   ```

   Once your partial view is returned, update the specific booking with the data returned.
3. **Use AJAX again, but return JSON.** Another way might be that you use AJAX again but instead you return JSON and do something with it. You could, for example, return text in which you would replace `Book` with; i.e. "Session full" or "Booked!".

   ```
   return new JsonResult
       {
           Data = "Booked!"
       }
   ```

Personally, I'd probably use AJAX to update with a non-AJAX (non-Javascript) fallback.

You can do this by using `@Ajax.ActionLink` and checking if the request is AJAX or not inside your controller action.

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest) {
    return PartialView("_OnlineBookingPartial", model);
}

return View();
```

This means that if the browser has Javascript enabled and supports AJAX, it will be used and the whole process will be seamless and instant for the user. If Javascript is disabled, the page will simply refresh.

Comment: Thanks Rowan, I agree this really is a "where to from here?" question. I'll refactor and give this a try :)